# Error ORA-02000 - QUERY keyword missing on MATERIALIZED VIEW

Tags: sql, oracle

this is my problem

```
  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW STRUTT_AFAM_RD (CD_ENTE, CD_STRUTTURA)
  TABLESPACE FLUSSI_SIA01D
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  USING INDEX 
  REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND NEXT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + 1, 'DD-MON-
  YYYY') || ' ' || '05:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  WITH ROWID USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
  USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION DISABLE QUERY 
  REWRITE
  AS (SELECT SUBSTR(S.CD_STRUTTURA_CUDES,1,3) CD_ENTE,
           S.CD_STRUTTURA_CUDES  CD_STRUTTURA
      FROM PONTE_EVESAN.STRUTTURE_FAM_AN@SEBP_PONTE_EVESAN S
     WHERE S.DT_FINE_VALIDITA IS NULL
       AND S.FL_ANNULLA = 0);

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I_SNAP$_SIAD_STRUTT_AFAM_RD ON STRUTT_AFAM_RD 
  (M_ROW$$) 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOLOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE FLUSSI_SIAD01D ;

  COMMENT ON MATERIALIZED VIEW STRUTT_AFAM_RD  IS 'STRUTTURE AFAM';
```

error :ORA-02000: parola chiave QUERY mancante(QUERY keyword missing)
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which database version do you use? What's that DISABLE line supposed to do, especially the COMPUTATION (key?)word?

This is 11g [CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302) documentation, read it & follow the syntax.

Anyway: have a  look at this code which is, actually, valid. Note the difference (I marked it with a comment):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW STRUTT_AFAM_RD
   (
   CD_ENTE,
   CD_STRUTTURA
   )
   TABLESPACE FLUSSI_SIA01D
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   USING INDEX
   REFRESH COMPLETE
           ON DEMAND
           NEXT TO_DATE (
                   TO_CHAR (SYSDATE + 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' ' || '05:00:00',
                   'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
           WITH ROWID
           USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
           USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS
   -- DISABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION DISABLE QUERY REWRITE  --> yours
   DISABLE QUERY REWRITE                                  --> mine
AS
   (SELECT SUBSTR (S.CD_STRUTTURA_CUDES, 1, 3) CD_ENTE,
           S.CD_STRUTTURA_CUDES CD_STRUTTURA
      FROM PONTE_EVESAN.STRUTTURE_FAM_AN@SEBP_PONTE_EVESAN S
     WHERE S.DT_FINE_VALIDITA IS NULL AND S.FL_ANNULLA = 0);
```